# Private Repositories not found in SmartGit

Tags: git, github, smartgit

we are using github for our projects. I was using smartgit without any problems. After my boss updated the account to "enterprise" SmartGit can't see all our private repositories on github.

[image]

Others git clients work just fine! (tested the github.com client for windows, console, SourceTree)

Why is this? I checked the remote repos and they are available.. smartgit tells me they are not (404).
Or is it because I am using smartgit personal edition and after the git update it doesn't like our git account so I need to buy smartgit commercial license?

Thanks.

Comment: Related link : https://help.github.com/articles/error-repository-not-found/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, SmartGit will use the GitHub OAuth token to access your repositories. If access restrictions have changed on GitHub, it may be necessary to regenerate this token in the **Preferences**, section **Hosting Providers**. Be sure to grant access to all your GitHub *organizations*. For details refer to the [SmartGit documentation](https://www.syntevo.com/doc/display/SG/GitHub+integration#GitHubintegration-PossibleProblems&Solutions).

Comment: thanks! you moved me in the right direction. I switched from OAuth to SSH and it works now perfectly. :)

Comment: another possibility that helped me was: settings->authentication: switch from smart-git-provided to system ssh client